# How to access variable from another function simultaneously in Python?

Tags: python

I have two functions.
How can I access variable from fun1 inside fun2 and vice versa?

```
def fun1(): 
    while True:
        x = m + n
        print(g)

def fun2():
    while True:
        g = a + b
        print(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO: question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `data-science` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: What is the real problem you are *trying* to solve? This is definitely [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variables as the function attributes.

```
def fun1(): 
    while True:
        fun1.x = m + n
        print(fun2.g)

def fun2():
    while True:
        fun2.g = a + b
        print(fun1.x)
```

OR

Make the variable global

```
    def fun1(): 
        while True:
            global x
            x = m + n
            print(g)

    def fun2():
            while True:
                global g
                g = a + b
                print(x)
```

Comment: Both of this only work if you are accessing variable from one function to another. Here, it is simultaneously. So both will fail. Since when you are executing fun1, it will show 'g' is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `g` are global variables (defined outside the scope of the functions), then you can access them inside either function.

That being said, I agree with Austin's comment above, that it sounds like you're asking how to fix your solution to a problem, rather than how to solve the problem...

Comment: Primary motive of this question is to how to access variable from one another simultaneously. So both of the above solution will fails, since when you are executing fun1, it will show 'g' is undefined.

Comment: What do you mean "simultaneously?" If these functions are part of the same process, then they never run at the same time. Or do they?
Initialize the variables x and g outside the functions. They will get updated each time the functions run.

And again... to reiterate the request from Austin above: If you post the original problem (that prompted you to attempt this idea), people might be able to find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

you can either make them part of an object/class if necessary

```
class Fun:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.g = 0
    def fun1(self):
        self.x = m + n
        print(self.g)
    def fun2(self):
        self.g = a + b
        print(self.x)
```

However i really recommend not using this unless it is specifically what you want instead you can try calling the function attributes:

```
def fun1(): 
    while True:
        fun1.x = m + n
        print(fun2.g)

def fun2():
    while True:
        fun2.g = a + b
        print(fun1.x)
```

or you can make the variable global but I won't recommend this as it leads to all sorts of problems!

```
def fun1(): 
   while True:
       global x
       x = m + n
       print(g)

def fun2():
    while True:
       global g
       g = a + b
       print(x)
```

Comment: Since the execution must be simultaneous, only object/class will work. I have tried the first one. But print(self.g) , this is resulting 0. class Fun:
    def __init__(self, a, b, m, n):
        self.x = 0
        self.g = 0
    def fun1(self):
        self.x = m + n
        print(self.g)
    def fun2(self):
        self.g = a + b
        print(self.x)

xyz = Fun(1, 2, 3, 4)
xyz.fun1()
xyz.fun2()